# How to configure tomcat6 to start from another directory

Tags: java, tomcat6

I have a problem.
I don't know how to configure tomcat6/webapps/ROOT/META-INF/context.xml for start my app from directory /home/myname/project/test/web/target/firsttest-1.1.0.SNAPSHOT.war
Help me, please! 
I can't search this problem with google

Comment: All context configuration is deployment directory relative, so you can place it inside any dir but in tomcat deployment directory.

Comment: Hmm.. Tell me please, it's mean that i can not config file for another dir? But if i move my dir "web" to /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/, it is not working by address https://localhost:8080/web (error: The requested resource (/web/) is not available)

Comment: copy your *.war into /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/ and go to: localhost:8080/firsttest or localhost:8080/firsttest-1.1.0.SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 0):

You can configure where Tomcat looks for configuration information using these environment variables:

CATALINA_HOME is where the tomcat binaries reside.

CATALINA_BASE is where the instance specific configuration files reside. This should look like a copy of the original Tomcat base directory with conf, logs, temp, webapps, and work folders.

So by setting up the CATALINA_BASE environment variable, you can configure Tomcat to run in multiple different configurations.